# How to do inline editing of a cell in table in an mvc application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a table in an MVC application within cshtml where Upon clicking on a link(href) present inside td, i need an inline editing of that cell(cell has to be expanded automatically) with textbox, update and cancel buttons, clicking update button saves the data and clicking cancel should redirect to original view.
Please let me know how to implement this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While there's a wealth of information here, this site is not a code writing service. To improve the quality of your Question, please show evidence of what research you have performed into this matter, including links to any pages that have been helpful or sound like they are likely to be related. Please show us any code you have tried and a description of the results you have received (including the full text of any error messages). [Look here for tips on writing a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You can achieve this by using [DataTable Editor - JQuery Plugin](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/submitButton.html) which is light, easy to use, responsive.

Comment: Thank you for your response, above plugin looks good but i wanted one textbox and 2 buttons,

Comment: I have a td   <td style="font-size:10px"><a href="#">Enter</a></td>

Comment: after clicking on link, i need a container/panel within that td(link should hide) with textbox and 2 buttons, i think its not recommended to change content inside plugin's right...??

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use a WebGrid. Follow this tutorial - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/996400/WebGrid-Inline-Edit-and-Delete-of-data-in-ASP-NET

Check this as well - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1110431/Gridview-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Comment: Thank you for your response, we already implemented with html table, so can't go for webgrid now.